# Discrete graph on chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to make a discrete graph with time intervals. I need to do something like [this](https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-discrete-panel) or [this](https://youtu.be/wJPBkPD1xuc)
Does anyone know how to do this on chartjs?